# Grounding dilemma

Tags: wiring

I'm replacing a standard 3-way toggle w/ a wifi-based 3-way switch and need a good ground connection to complete the wiring.  There is a ground w/in the plastic junction box but it is a bundle that passes thru without connecting to anything.  How can it connect to this ground 'bundle' and expect a good connection??  Tnx !!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add a picture of the interior of this box to your question? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box in question please?

Comment: By the way, that's wrong; they should have a grounding pigtail going to the switch.